# vk код, который не виден в исходном коде, когда замного написал

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

как через selenium получить ответ, что сообщение больше писать не может? В исходном коде одно совпадение по поиску и то не важно написал что-нить или нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="im-page--error _im_error" style="display: block;">Сообщение не может быть отправлено, так как Вы разослали слишком много сообщений за последнее время.</div>




<span class="im-mess--marker _im_mess_marker" aria-label="Ошибка при отправке сообщения" role="link"></span>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы всё ботами на селениуме промышляете)))

Comment: напишите, по какому локатору пытаетесь искать

Comment: )) Исследовать элемент в Chrome показывает "im-page--error _im_error" и "im-mess--marker _im_mess_marker" соответственно. В исходном коде из нету или частичное совпадение и то в скрипте, так понимаю динамические элементы, вне зависимости переступила ли я лимит на сообщения в день или нет. дневной 20 сообщений лимит на новые контакты. Другими словами эти две ошибки повторяться при попытке отправить сообщение, но в исходном коде их не видно, или я не вижу)) ибо это скрипт или динамические элементы, если я правильно понимаю

Comment: а пробовали по тексту ошибки искать элемент? Он то точно есть. Было бы идеально, если бы вы HTML такой страницы показали, а то так то сложно думать как его найти

Comment: в браузере воспользуйтесь сочетанием Ctrl+Shift+C (это режим указателя), укажите мышкой на ошибку, и он просветиться в коде страницы.

Comment: Так же (по теме пользования SO), когда вы пишете вопрос, вы всегда получаете уведомления о том, что кто-то прокомментировал или ответил (автор всегда получает уведомления), а вот что-бы комментирующий участник получил уведомление, что вы ответили на его комментарий, упомяните в тексте комментария его ник с Собачкой в начале - @AtachiShadow

Comment: То есть, Автор всегда получает уведомления о деятельности в его вопросе. А посторонние пользователи только после упоминания своего ника)))